# Android N device size changes restarting Activity

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat

In Android N user can change the Device Size in settings,Activity is crashing while changing Native display size. after recovery icons/alignments was not proper. Is there any way to handle this. 
unable to find anything in ADB logs.

```
03-29 10:55:01.479 I/WindowManager( 2121): Screen frozen for +1s52ms due to Window{c6348b2 u0 com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}
03-29 10:55:01.496 I/WindowManager( 2121): Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1738 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:816 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1343 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2302 
03-29 10:55:01.751 D/TileUtils( 1757): getCategories took 10 ms
03-29 10:55:01.761 I/Choreographer( 1757): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

03-29 10:55:01.969 W/MessageBubbleBackground( 1757): onMeasure called; width:526, height:287
03-29 10:55:01.969 W/MessageBubbleBackground( 1757): onMeasure called; width:931, height:457
03-29 10:55:01.970 W/MessageBubbleBackground( 1757): onMeasure called; width:931, height:457
03-29 10:55:01.970 W/MessageBubbleBackground( 1757): onMeasure called; width:526, height:287
03-29 10:55:02.322 I/Keyboard.Facilitator( 2605): onFinishInput()
03-29 10:55:02.416 W/MessageBubbleBackground( 1757): onMeasure called; width:931, height:457
03-29 10:55:02.417 W/MessageBubbleBackground( 1757): onMeasure called; width:526, height:287
03-29 10:55:03.492 I/art     ( 2121): Starting a blocking GC Explicit
03-29 10:55:03.589 I/art     ( 2121): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 14221(688KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(60KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 31MB/47MB, paused 1.075ms total 96.371ms
03-29 10:55:04.326 D/ActivityManager( 2121): finishRunningVoiceLocked()  >>>>
03-29 10:55:04.327 D/audio_hw_primary( 1777): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
03-29 10:55:04.339 D/audio_hw_primary( 1777): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
03-29 10:55:04.339 D/msm8974_platform( 1777): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
03-29 10:55:04.340 D/audio_hw_primary( 1777): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
03-29 10:55:04.343 D/audio_hw_primary( 1777): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
03-29 10:55:04.352 E/UserRestrictionsUtils( 2121): Unknown restriction: null
03-29 10:55:04.427 D/TileUtils( 1757): getCategories took 13 ms
03-29 10:55:04.584 I/Keyboard.Facilitator( 2605): onFinishInput()
03-29 10:55:04.825 I/WindowManager( 2121): Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1738 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:816 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1343 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2302 
03-29 10:55:05.689 D/PhoneStatusBar( 2638): disable: < expand ICONS* alerts SYSTEM_INFO* back home recent clock search quick_settings >
03-29 10:55:07.249 I/ActivityManager( 2121): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.sample.ui/.MyActivity} from uid 10110 on display 0
03-29 10:55:07.255 D/audio_hw_primary( 1777): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
03-29 10:55:07.257 D/ActivityManager( 2121): finishRunningVoiceLocked()  >>>>
03-29 10:55:07.300 D/AudioFlinger( 1777): mixer(0xb0783780) throttle end: throttle time(4)
03-29 10:55:07.303 D/com.sample.ui.MyActivity:  ---- onDestroy() -----
03-29 10:55:07.348 I/WindowManager( 2121): Destroying surface Surface(name=com.sample.ui/com.sample.ui.MyActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:1738 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:816 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1343 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2302
```

Comment: Did you try to stop activity from restarting when configuration is changed? (You need to do it in the manifest file)

Comment: I handled like this in manifest file android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection|screenSize|screenLayout|"

is there any parameter to handle display size

Comment: `... device size changes`... What's that? a Transformer phone?!

Comment: This is default option provided from google N onwards along with font size. I  am using nexus 6 device running on android N. you can find more on below blog.thanks...
http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/10/android-n-feature-spotlight-easily-change-your-devices-display-dpi-with-screen-zoom/

Comment: Read the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#screen-zoom) regarding how your app should handle display density changes.

Comment: @Gopi Krishna you can use "density" as parameter. It's not in the doc yet but it works as expected.